# Trouble In Implementing Google Maps In the Application

Tags: android, dictionary

i am Trying to Implement Google Maps in my Application, i have Fragment the code like this :

```
 map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());

int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
if(resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
{
    Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, getActivity(),  
69);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
  //  dialog.setOnDismissListener(getOnDismissListener());
    dialog.show();
}

Log.d("GooglePlayServicesUtil Check", "Result is: " + resultCode);
}
```

and my XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
     class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyABcmhLoZuEuU6eMSlwWGA1_IrEKR3L5n8"
    />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

when the app Runs, i Can see The map Borders, and Zoomin / Zoomout Button , But i Get 2 Errors , First

```
 Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence   
 referenced from method glt.a
```

and after a few seconds I get This Error :

```
 Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an   
 authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I Have Just ReCreated my Key by Going to The SHA1 Finger Print From Eclipse's Windows,Preferences,Android,Build,SHA1 FingerPrint and Creating In Google :

```
 API Project / APIS & AUTH / Credentials / Create New Key / Android Key
```

Like this:

```
     2A:61:79:6F:3D:41:9E:C9:81:F5:C0:49:EE:F8:CA:09:04:0C:3A:AE;com.lifemate.lmmessenger.mapspack
```

(My Class is com.lifemate.lmmessenger.mapspack.maps) and here is My Manifest :

```
     <uses-permission   
android:name="com.lifemate.lmmessenger.mapspack.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

 <IS THE UPPER ONE RIGHT? (My Class is the maps.Java>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


<Application ...

 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyABcmhLoZuEuU6eMSlwWGA1_IrEKR3L5n8" />
```

I Have Added the Google Play Services Jar and Project to my Application, Am i Missing Some thing Guys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using Android Key with namespace you must use the signed application (generate apk with key)

If you use application to testing just delete this and leave blank:

```
2A:61:79:6F:3D:41:9E:C9:81:F5:C0:49:EE:F8:CA:09:04:0C:3A:AE;com.lifemate.lmmessenger.mapspack
```

Comment: My Application is YET at Testing Level , And its Not APK Yet, So i Should Use Blank Key ?!!

Comment: If you app will be at production level just restore this key, should  work